# Make two canvases show the same thing

Tags: unity-game-engine, user-interface

Lately, I'm trying to make two canvases show the same thing,
one being world space, the other being a screen space - Overlay.
I want to do this because when I'm in a menu screen space one is displayed and then you exit it and it is updated on the world space one.
I hope you know what I'm trying to ask :)

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of making two canvases, one being world space and the other being overlay, I made a script that when it is clicked it changes the canvas to overlay.

Script:

```
void EnterBoard() {
    canvas.renderMode = RenderMode.ScreenSpaceOverlay;
}
void ExitBoard() {
    canvase.renderMode = RenderMode.WorldSpace;
}
```

This makes the canvas overlay and then changes to world space when exiting it.